# How to generate hard instances for number partitioning?

Tags: optimization, benchmark, test-instances

I am trying to compare the performance of some algorithms for [multiway number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning). I run them on randm instances that I generate with Python's numpy:

```
values = np.random.randint(1,1000, 100000)
```

Then I run the algorithm for partitioning the values into 10 bins. But in all instances that I try, the simple [greedy number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_number_partitioning) algorithm returns an optimal partition (all sums are the same up to 1).

- What is a dataset of large real-world number partitioning problems, that are hard (that is, cannot be solved easily by exhaustive search or by a greedy algorithm)?
- How can one generate such large instances randomly?

Comment: A first idea is to replace the uniform distribution by another distribution, a normal one for example. Second, you can increase the number of bins, so that you end up with about 3 to 5 items in bins

Comment: I don't know if there are standard datasets for the Multiway Number Partitioning Problem, but there are some for the Bin Packing Problem http://or.dei.unibo.it/library/bpplib from which you could built Multiway Number Partitioning instances

Comment: Seconding the comment by @fontanf about a different distribution, you might also try a mixture distribution, for instance taking part of the sample from a distribution with low mean and another part from a distribution with high mean (and perhaps a lower bound greater than the mean or even max of the first sample).

Comment: Since the 1D bin packing problem is very similar to the number partitioning problem, you may be able to find hard problem sets from that literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ["Optimal Multi-Way Number Partitioning"](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3184400) (Schreiber, Korf and Moffitt, JACM 2018) the authors present experiments with random integers with 16, 32 and 48 bits. 16 bit integers are relatively easy, since most random instances have a perfect partition. 32 bit integers are harder, and with 48 bit integers, almost all instances do not have a perfect partition. So, to generate hard instances for number partitioning, one can simply increase the number of bits (and then, even instances with 100 integers are already hard):

```
values = np.random.randint(1,2**48-1, 100)
```